# Screen resolution

Tags: java, android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm writing a real-time Android game, so I need to be able to handle different aspect ratios and resolutions correctly.

For now, I'm using my Samsung Fascinate. My phone's specifications indicate that the screen resolution is 480x800. But when I check the screen resolution in the game, it says 533x320 instead...

Why is this?

Comment: Conclusion about how to get real resolution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824193/htc-sensation-real-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Manifest add a:

```
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

This behavior is discussed in detail on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) under the section:

"2. Auto-scaling of pixel dimensions and coordinates"